# Send HTTP requests from NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I have a NextJS application running on a NodeJS server that will serve as the frontend of my three-tier application.

```js
'use client';

import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent }  from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

import { useState } from 'react'

import { storeData } from '../../constants';

export default function ReviewPage(){
    const [ selectedStore, setSelectedStore ] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        setSelectedStore(event.target.value as string);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        const response = fetch("some_backend/path")
    }

    return (
        <>
        {/* FORM */}
        <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Store</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        label="store"
                        value={selectedStore}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                        {/* Map the stores to populate the Select field */}
                        {storeData.map(store => <MenuItem key={store.id} value={store.name}>{store.name}</MenuItem>)}  
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item>
                <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="contained">Analyse</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        {/* Results */}
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper elevation={3} sx={{padding: "15px"}}>
                    Why do we use it?
                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper elevation={3} sx={{padding: "15px"}}>
                    Why do we use it?
                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </>
    )
}
```

Calling `fetch` from `handleChange` sends the request to the backend from the browser. Ideally, the backend will be deployed on an internal only network (therefore not accessible from the client browser). How can I send a request to a backend from the NodeJS server itself rather than from the client browser.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I haven't been able to find an answer so far. Am I doing the wrong thing? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can certainly have one server-side process (like Next.js) proxy requests through to an internal network but any app that runs in the browser needs to be able to reach whatever API it's communicating with. It's not clear from your question whether your _"backend"_ is the Next.js server or some other process

Comment: The backend server is a Python Flask server.

Answer (score -1):

More than one way to do it but ideally you would `.pipe` the http request and response through your proxy. Something like:

```
import http from 'node:http';
async function route(request,response,user){
  //if user is x,y,or z
  const creq = http.request(opts, (cres) => {
    cres.pipe(response);
  });
  request.pipe(creq);
}
```